# Elasticsearch: Is it possible to reference properties in mappings?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a simple mapping in elasticsearch-6, like this.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "fields": {
          "properties": {
            "meta": {
              "properties": {
                "task": {
                  "properties": {
                    "field1": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "field2": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have to add another property to it - `tasks` which is just an array of the `task` property already defined.

Is there a way to reference the properties of `task` so that I don't have to duplicate all the properties? Something like:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "properties": {
      "meta": {
        "properties": {
          "tasks": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": "fields.properties.meta.properties.task"
          },
          "task": {
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can already use your `task` field as an array of `task` objects, only, you cannot query them independently. If your goal is to achieve this (as I assume from your second example), I would directly set the "nested" data type into the mapping of the `task` field - then, yes, you'll need to reindex.

I can't imagine a use case where you would need the same array of objects duplicated in two fields, with one nested and the other not.

**EDIT**

Below, some considerations/suggestions based on the discussion in the comments:

- One field can have either one value or an array of values. In your case, your task field can have either one task object or an array of task objects. You should only care about setting the "nested" datatype for task, if you plan to query its objects independently (of course, if they are more than one)
- I would suggest to design your documents in such a way to avoid duplicated information in the first place. Duplicated information will make your documents bigger and more complex to process, leading to greater storage requirements and slower queries
- If it's not possible to redesign your document mapping, you might check whether [alias datatypes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/alias.html) can help you avoiding some repetitions.
- If it's not possible to redesign your document mapping, you might check whether [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/dynamic-templates.html) can help you avoiding some repetitions

Comment: My elasticsearch data comes from logs, and in my application I can log a single task or a list of tasks which is why I need both.

Comment: But you don't need two fields for this, one is enough. One field can have either one value or an array of values. In your case, your `task` field can have either one task object or an array of task objects. You should only care about setting the "nested" datatype for `task`, if you plan to query its objects independently (of course, if they are more than one)

Comment: Glad it helped! maybe you can mark your question as answered :)

Comment: How would you solve the case where there is an object (not an array) with a lot of fields, and some of those fields needs to reference other mapped fields?

Comment: Why would you reference other mapped fields? because you don't want to specify the same mapping twice or because you want to duplicate fields?

Comment: Both. Consider this simple example: { request: {body: {key: 'keyword', key2, ...}, params: {key1, key2, ...}}...There is already a mapping for params used somewhere else in the code, so that can be referenced here. So I don't want to specify the mapping of `params` twice, and the mappings of params are duplicated which is fine. I just don't want to rewrite them twice.

Comment: Two observations. First, I would suggest you to redesign your documents in such a way to avoid duplicated information (because bigger and more complex documents translate in slower queries and more storage space). Second, if you cannot redesign your document  mapping, you might want to have a look at [alias datatypes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/alias.html).

Comment: Thanks. Refactoring is a whole different game that is out of my scope for now, but the `alias` is a step in the right direction. Unfortunately because of the restrictions I won't be able to make use of it. Seems like this is not possible without some duplication. If you can include this in the answer and the link to alias, I will be happy to accept.